# Multiparametric Selection with self join

Tags: sql-server, self-join

sorry not have been enough clear in the title but I do not know how to summarize my request:
if somebody want to suggest, I will amend it.

Back to the question:
I want to translate to T-SQL some routines now performed in classic ASP

have 2 tables:

```
Users and Messages
```

Users is like this:

```
ID  USERID      ROLE        CLASS       PARENTOF        SUBJECTS
13  CarolineW   parent                  BillC,JohnC    
12  IsabelF     parent                  AlexG,AnnG    
11  SaraW       teacher                                 MATH-3a,MATH-4a,MATH-5b,MATH-1a
10  JohnT       teacher                                 ENG-4a,GEO-2a,GEO-1a
9   MatildaW    student     4a       
8   JohnC       student     2a       
7   AlexG       student     4a       
6   CamillaH    student     4a       
5   BillC       student     2a       
4   AnnG        student     1a 
3   KarlK       admin       
2   AnnF        control
1   BillT       superadmin
```

while message among others has following fields:

```
ID  SELECTOR            SENDTO                  SENDER       ANSWERED
13  4a,JohnC,JohnT      parent,student          admin        CarolineW,IsabelF
12  4a,4b,SaraW         parent                  ....         Null
11  1a                  teacher,parent          SaraW        JohnT,IsabelF                                 
10  1a                  teacher,admin           IsabelF      Null
```

.....

Rules:
all users can send a message to everybody else setting 2 parameters:
Selector that is the target
SendTo that defines the connection to the target:

ie: Message ID11 has (class) 1a as target and teacher and parents as SendTo:
this means that message has to be forwarded to all teacher and parents of student of class 1a

Message ID13 has to be sent to all parents and student of class 4a, to parents and to himself of JohnC (since is a student) and to students of JohnT (since is a Teacher).

on the other side, since messages will also available on the electronic Board of the school, I want that each user when access to its account can read all the messages addressed to him according to the above rules.

finally would list all users who have not answered yet the message.

currently I've performed such result using some for/next loops in classic asp but I was wondering if a T-SQL solution was more efficient, and surely more elegant, byt my knowledge in T-SQL is very limited and so far I've only been able to
extract messages adressed to student or to parents but using 2 different queries although almost identical, but missing some controls and target is to have a single query

or is it not possible?

can indicate the path to follow to achieve such result?

considering the amount of users (less than 500) actual routines although surely not efficient do not have a big impact on the server: main Target is therefore not to improve performance but with learning purposes.

Thanks for any suggestion and comment.

Joe

Rules:
all users can send a message to everybody else setting 2 parameters:
Selector that is the target
SendTo that defines the connection to the target:

ie: Message ID11 has (class) 1a as target and teacher and parents as SendTo:
this means that message has to be forwarded to all teacher and parents of student of class 1a

Message ID13 has to be sent to all parents and student of class 4a, to parents and to himself of JohnC (since is a student) and to students of JohnT (since is a Teacher).

on the other side, since messages will also available on the electronic Board of the school, I want that each user when access to its account can read all the messages addressed to him according to the above rules.

finally would list all users who have not answered yet the message.

currently I've performed such result using some for/next loops in classic asp but I was wondering if a T-SQL solution was more efficient, and surely more elegant, byt my knowledge in T-SQL is very limited and so far I've only been able to
extract messages adressed to student or to parents but using 2 different queries although almost identical, but missing some controls and target is to have a single query

or is it not possible?

can indicate the path to follow to achieve such result?

considering the amount of users (less than 500) actual routines although surely not efficient do not have a big impact on the server: main Target is therefore not to improve performance but with learning purposes.

Thanks for any suggestion and comment.

Joe

Comment: You might investigate about database normalization, with the structure as given it will be always be unpleasant to work.

Comment: Hi!
thanks for your comment.. but what you mean about database normalization?
from what I read about normalization main principle is to avoid redundancy and with structure adopted info are set 1 time only:
can give me some more hints?
TKS